# serialization confusion ?with json and SOAP service

Tags: java, serialization

i know serialization is saving or transferring object state
I am confused with serialization
suppose I send a json request to server using Gson library and my request Object is does not implement  serilizable interface.

So Gson library conver my object to json string and sent it across as btyes so does java serilization comes in picture or not.

Same case in SOAP request where object are converted in xml.

where does java serilization play role in this services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Serialization is internal java mechanism. Java may choose to serialize objects whenever it needs it or you can invoke it. When you mark your class as implementing Serializable interface you tell java that this class may be serialized and deserialized by its internal serialization mechanism. However, there are other options for persistency - serialize your object to JSON or XML or your own custom format. If you use external library such as Gson Jackson JSON, XML parser or anything like this the Serializable interface is irrelevant and java serialization does not come into the picture

Comment: so where serialization works only in socket communication or it can used in http communication.I have never used serialization.people talk about saving object in files or sending across network.In real example why we actually store object in files or sent object across network.today every communication happens in json or xml.are people still using serilization?

Comment: Serialization is a general term that means persisting your in-memory objects into some textual form with ability to restore it back. Internal java serialization is java's own tool to do so. It uses it when working with sockets. You also can invoke it on your own but this is rarely done. You are correct, today it is very popular to rely on externally provided serialization into well known formats, such as JSON or XML. Those are preferred formats for sending over http. However, you could choose to use Java serialization mechanism, but it is not usually done

Comment: Thanks Michael for ur time!!